# spacy-lookup punctuation interference

Tags: nlp, spacy, text-processing

[Spacy-lookup](https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-lookup) is an entity matcher for very large dictionaries, which uses the FlashText module.
It seems that punctuation in the second case below prevents it from matching the entity.

Does someone know why this occurs and how it can be solved?

```
import spacy
from spacy_lookup import Entity

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable = ['NER'])
entity = Entity(keywords_list=['vitamin D'])
nlp.add_pipe(entity, last=True)

#works for this sentence:
doc = nlp("vitamin D is contained in this.")
print([token.text for token in doc if token._.is_entity])
#['vitamin D']

#does not work for this sentence:
doc = nlp("This contains vitamin D.")
print([token.text for token in doc if token._.is_entity])
#[]
```

*edit*: interestingly, this does not occur when one directly uses the flashtext library (upon which spacy-lookup is based) :

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
keyword_processor = KeywordProcessor()
keyword_processor.add_keyword('vitamin D')
keywords_found = keyword_processor.extract_keywords("This contains vitamin D.", span_info=True)
print(keywords_found)
# [('vitamin D', 14, 23)]
```

*edit* : As Anwarvic pointed out, the problem comes from the way the default tokenizer is splitting the string.
*edit* : I am trying to find a general solution which does not for example involve adding spaces before every punctuation point. (basically looking for a solution which does not involve reformatting the input text)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple ... put **space** after "D" like so:

```
>>> doc = nlp("This contains vitamin D .") #<-- space after D
>>> print([token.text for token in doc if token._.is_entity])
['vitamin D']
```

Why does it happen? Simply because spaCy considered "D." as a whole token the same way the "D." in the name "D. Cooper" is considered a whole token!

Comment: Thanks for your answer (which I upvoted), it made me realize that the problem is with the tokenizer.  I will look into adjusting the rules used by the tokenizer. However adding an additional pre-processing step to add spaces as you mentioned would not work well in my application as the keyword list will have many thousand keywords and systematically adding spaces before punctuation points might cause other parts of the application not not work correctly

Comment: You can add a space only when there is "vitamin D" at the end

Comment: 'Vitamin D' was just one example where this phenomenon occurs. There are many others such as 'Protein kinase C' etc.. To implement the adding spaces method I would have to run flash text as a pre-processing step just to detect where spaces should be added and then run it again through spacy-lookup to tag the entities. Such a method would not be computationally efficient. I will try to modify the tokenizer or the source code of spacy-lookup to produce a solution which is computationally fast and with low memory usage. Thanks for figuring out that the problem comes from the tokenizer.